# Get the position of record against the table (ORDER BY ID)

Tags: sql

The question is straight forward:

i have a table:

```
id  name
1   one
2   two 
3   three
4   four 
5   five
```

Now what i want is the Id and the row position, against the table itself and not the result (**ROW_NUMBER**)

imagine now i want the row position of the Id 3 and 4:

```
id rowpos

3   3
4   4
```

now i remove the first record and i do the same query:

id rowpos

```
3   2
4   3
```

I would like an agnostic answer, but a response in any major DBMS‎ is fine if improves performance.

I'm having some problem in finding the answer to this question, because i could bet that was answered before.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER` along with a subquery:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT id, rn AS rowpos
FROM cte
WHERE id IN (3, 4)
ORDER BY id;
```

Note that the CTE is necessary to first compute the row number over the entire table.  Then, we can restrict to only the `id` values you want to see in the final output.

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle (from 12.1 onwards) we also have the [row limiting clause](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/row-limiting-clause-for-top-n-queries-12cr1):

```
select * from regions
order by region_id
offset 2 rows fetch next 2 rows only;
```